# Partitionwise join not working for range filter

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with the same partitions and subpartitions. They are both partitioned by `group_id` (`text`) and subpartitioned by year using `created_at` (`timestamptz`). I have made much more simplified tables here to make the question easier to understand:

```sql
create table if not exists items (
    group_id text,
    item_id integer,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    primary key (group_id, created_at, item_id)
) partition by list (group_id);

-- Partition by group ID.
create table items_a partition of items for values in ('a') partition by range (created_at);
create table items_b partition of items for values in ('b') partition by range (created_at);

-- Partition by year.
create table items_a2022 partition of items_a for values from ('2022-01-01') to ('2023-01-01');
create table items_a2023 partition of items_a for values from ('2023-01-01') to ('2024-01-01');
create table items_b2022 partition of items_b for values from ('2022-01-01') to ('2023-01-01');
create table items_b2023 partition of items_b for values from ('2023-01-01') to ('2024-01-01');

create table if not exists things (
    group_id text,
    item_id integer,
    item_created_at timestamp with time zone,
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id, item_created_at, item_id) REFERENCES items (group_id, created_at, item_id)
) partition by list(group_id);

-- Partition by group ID.
create table things_a partition of things for values in ('a') partition by range (item_created_at);
create table things_b partition of things for values in ('b') partition by range (item_created_at);

-- Partition by year.
create table things_a2022 partition of things_a for values from ('2022-01-01') to ('2023-01-01');
create table things_a2023 partition of things_a for values from ('2023-01-01') to ('2024-01-01');
create table things_b2022 partition of things_b for values from ('2022-01-01') to ('2023-01-01');
create table things_b2023 partition of things_b for values from ('2023-01-01') to ('2024-01-01');
```

A few rows to help testing:

```sql
insert into items (group_id, item_id, created_at) values ('a', 1, '2022-01-01');
insert into items (group_id, item_id, created_at) values ('b', 2, '2023-06-10');
insert into things (group_id, item_id, item_created_at) values ('a', 1, '2022-01-01');
```

Enabling partition-wise joins:

```
set enable_partitionwise_join = on;
```

Querying `items` for one year and group ID prunes as expected where only one of four possible `items` tables (`items_a2022`) is queried:

```
explain
select count(*)
from items
where items.created_at >= '2022-05-01'::timestamptz
    and items.created_at <= '2022-06-01'::timestamptz
    and items.group_id = 'a';
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=8.18..8.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using items_a2022_pkey on items_a2022 items  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((group_id = 'a'::text) AND (created_at >= '2022-05-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2022-06-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
        Heap Fetches: 0
```

When I join to `things` however:

```
explain
select count(*)
from items
join things on things.item_id = items.item_id
    and things.item_created_at = items.created_at
    and things.group_id = items.group_id
where items.created_at >= '2022-05-01'::timestamptz
    and items.created_at <= '2022-06-01'::timestamptz
    and items.group_id = 'a';
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=56.67..56.68 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..56.67 rows=1 width=0)
        Join Filter: ((items.item_id = things.item_id) AND (items.created_at = things.item_created_at))
        ->  Index Only Scan using items_a2022_pkey on items_a2022 items  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=44)
              Index Cond: ((group_id = 'a'::text) AND (created_at >= '2022-05-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= '2022-06-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..48.31 rows=12 width=44)
              ->  Seq Scan on things_a2022 things_1  (cost=0.00..24.12 rows=6 width=44)
                    Filter: (group_id = 'a'::text)
              ->  Seq Scan on things_a2023 things_2  (cost=0.00..24.12 rows=6 width=44)
                    Filter: (group_id = 'a'::text)
```

I expected that `enable_partitionwise_join` being `true` would cause `things` to be pruned but it only does on group ID, not the year. Therefore both `things_a2022` and `things_a2023` are used. I wondered was partition-wise joins not supported for subpartitions, but it seems this is not the case considering if I change to `=` rather than `<=` it does work as expected:

```
explain
select count(*)
from items
join things on things.item_id = items.item_id
    and things.item_created_at = items.created_at
    and things.group_id = items.group_id
where items.created_at = '2022-05-01'::timestamptz
    and items.group_id = 'a';
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=35.14..35.15 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.15..35.14 rows=1 width=0)
        Join Filter: (items.item_id = things.item_id)
        ->  Index Only Scan using items_a2022_pkey on items_a2022 items  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=44)
              Index Cond: ((group_id = 'a'::text) AND (created_at = '2022-05-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
        ->  Seq Scan on things_a2022 things  (cost=0.00..26.95 rows=1 width=44)
              Filter: ((item_created_at = '2022-05-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (group_id = 'a'::text))
```

We have tested with Postgres 13 (our production version) but also version 15. Does anybody know why partition-wise joins are only partially applied in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, these are far too few rows to for a useful test. But even with enough rows you wouldn't get partition pruning on `things`, because PostgreSQL's intelligence is not sufficient to make the deduction.

PostgreSQL can perform a partitionwise join with subpartitions. If you omit your `WHERE` condition and insert enough rows, you can verify that.